# Can angular ui loader handle complex cases with multiple views?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have an app with multiple columns (about 3 columns as least), each column is a more detailed view of an item in a column on its left. This type of layout is similar to Asana's.

Lets take an example from 1 of the page I currently have:

1. Column 1 list all current users, clicking on 1 user will open a list of all sales orders of that user on column 2.
2. Column 2 show list of all orders of 1 selected user on column 1. Clicking on 1 order will show the details of that order
3. Column 3 show all details of an order selected on column 2. Clicking on a shipment in that order details will show the details of the shipment
4. Column 4 show all the details of a shipment selected on column 3

So on a so forth. Now there is another twist:
Column 2,3,4 show these details in a form, which mean they can be edited and submitted. Once they are submitted, it makes sense to reload all the column on the left of that edited column to refresh the info. However, for performance purpose I would like to reload them all in a single request and send them back in one json array hen update each column that has newly returned view code (lets assume the backend code is smart enough to handle all this)

I believe someone must have had this issue before, what is your solution to get around this?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are loading different set of data. Its good not load them all at once. You can use ng-include and the the content of the ng-include can be triggered based on the clicks.

```
ng-inclue="<<scope variable>>"
```

For ex. In your controller,
 Chnage the value of salesurl based on user action

```
<div class="slide-animate" ng-include="salesurl"></div>
```

The scope variable can be an URL, which renders the result set based on the parameters posted after user action.

Hope this help.

Comment: Interesting, can we somehow provide accessible routing for that though? For example: can we have 
1. /users/
2. /users/1
3. /users/1/orders/1
4. /users/1/orders/1/shipment/1

Comment: Yeah, When you change the URL for that particular variable the corresponding pages will be loaded .